# Young Cylander stows away to visit Earth

Tags: story-identification, space-station

This is a novella or novel I read in the 90s. The main character was a teen who had spent his life on a large orbital space station. The station was known as Cyland (not sure about the spelling) because it was cylindrical in shape, and its inhabitants were referred to as Cylanders. There might have been several such stations.

Cyland had periodic, planned "rain days" for irrigation, during which most people stayed indoors. There was an illustration of a figure walking in the rain, captioned with a quote from the text: "*A few eccentrics liked walking in it.*"

The MC dreamed of visiting Earth, and told his father he'd like to experience real rain. His father reminded him he never liked rain days.

The MC and a friend stowed away on an Earth-bound ship, with help from an older relative or friend who worked on the ship. He found them somewhere to hide on Earth and told them he'd meet them later, but never returned.

Eventually his sister/(girl)friend(?) found them and explained that he'd died in a car crash and she had no way to get them onto the ship home. They went to the authorities for help. I remember the person they spoke to being unimpressed but understanding.

Comment: This really sounds like something CJ Cherryh would have written.  One of the planets in her universe is called "Cyteen". I think I have a collection of her short fiction.